# VS Code quoteStyle doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

All other imports and strings on the file uses ", but when VS Code auto import some class it uses '. Typescript and Javascript quoteStyle are defined to auto.
If i change the settings to double the imports occurs with ".

Image illustrating the problem:
[image: All other imports vs last auto import]

Now my question, is there any other VS Code or Typescript settings that may be influencing that behaviour? Or maybe it's a bug?

Didn't find anything related on vscode or typescript repositories.

UPDATE: Seems to be something on my Angular project, because on others projects its working as intended. But I didn't find the cause yet.

Comment: Do you have any extension installed? I've seen this behavior with conflicting rules from prettier extension for example.

Comment: Hi @Clafou, I just tested with all extensions disabled and the behavior was the same, when quoteStyle is auto it uses single quotes.

Comment: Sorry but I think I did not get your question. What do you want to achieve and doesn't work as intendend? Is it the fact that you want to leave your setting `javascript.preferences.quoteStyle` to `auto` and VSCode to infer the new import?
I found this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26882 but I'm not sure if it's related to your problem or not.

Comment: Hi @Clafou, I want to leave my quoteStyle to auto, but even on a file with a lot of double quoted imports, like in the image, VS Code still imports with single quotes. The issue that you linked is about splitting auto on two new options, auto single and auto double, that will only change its behaviour on the first import of the files.